# Is it possible to network two kubernetes clusters such that resources not publicly exposed in one can be accessed by the other?

Tags: kubernetes

I have deployed a rather large application and I have the need to segregate some of my deployments, which I normally access via cluster ip, into their own dedicated cluster. Once I have done this is there a way I can still allow deployments in cluster a to continue access deployments in cluster b, without exposing them to the internet? These are highly sensitive workloads and exposing them to the internet is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

To reach resources deployed in a Kubernetes cluster from outside, you need to expose those resources. No other ways.

Of course, if you have the Kubernetes clusters in your local network, it is not necessary to expose them to the Internet.

Comment: I didn't say from outside... Just from two clusters, they can even be two in the same data center.

Comment: I meant, outside the cluster, not outside the network. You need to expose Kubernetes cluster resources to reach them outside the cluster.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use and configure [Contiv](http://contiv.github.io/) and [Calico](https://www.projectcalico.org/) in a way that you can have pods in cluster 1 being technically able to talk to pods in cluster 2 without exposing services. Although you also shouldn't forget that this is simply IP based communication and services like e.g. DNS wont be unified right away. So you can't just simple connect by services or pod names.

Comment: Thanks, are there any documents up on how to use these to network two clusters?